# RegEx: How to refer to multiple occurrences of a subexpression in a replacement string

Tags: regex, variables, replace, intellij-idea, find

Not sure if this is possible, but I'm trying to do a dynamic Find/Replace in IntelliJ IDEA...

In my Java project, there are several methods that contain string concatenation like this:

`return "[foo=" + foo + ", bar=" + bar + ", this=" + this + ", that=" + that + "]";`

I wrote the following RegEx to find all of these occurrences:

`return (\"[^\"]+\")+((\s\+\s)+([\pL\pN\r\s]*)+(\s\+\s)+(\"[^\"]+\"))*;`

Now I want to replace these concatenations with equivalent `String.format()` returns, like this:

`return String.format("[foo=%s, bar=%s, this=%s, that=%s]", foo, bar, this, that);`

My replacement RegEx looks like this so far:

`return String.format\($1$6,$4\);`

...but a couple of things are happening here, and a couple of tricky requirements.

1. `$4` is empty.
2. `$6` only returns the last occurrence of `(\"[^\"]+\")`.
3. I need to produce ", $4" for each occurrence of `$4`.
4. I need to strip the quotation marks out of `$1` and `$6` and append a "%s" after any "=" signs.

Is this possible? Any idea how to do it, allowing for concatenation of any number of strings?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is a link to the IntelliJ docs: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/finding-and-replacing-text-in-file.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Regex find-and-replace. If you put your cursor in the middle your your String concatenation, a yellow light bulb should appear. If you click the light bulb (or better yet, alt-Enter), it should give you at least three different refactorings of that line of code.

See the Intentions documentation [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Intentions).

Comment: Is there anything IntelliJ can't do? *swoon*